# Restrict PR completion if feature branch is behind. Azure Devops

Tags: git, azure-devops, pull-request

Is there anyway, I can restrict PR completion if my feature branch is behind the compare branch(in this case Master).

I want to create a 2 PRs

1. feature/1 to develop. Because, feature/1 is 3 behind master I want to restrict completion of this PR.
2. feature/2 to develop. Since this feature branch is in sync with master branch, no restrictions should apply on this PR.

**NOTE**: feature branches are created from master

Thanks

[image]

Comment: May I know how's the status of this? Does below work around is help to you? You can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if below is work for you. Free to share comment if any question you have:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We haven't provide such out-of-box feature in branch policy to help you achieve this goal until now.

But there has one work around you can consider to use: Perform the judgment of whether the value of `behind` is 0 in Build pipeline via [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/stats/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1), then specify this pipeline as **Build validation** in the branch policy.

---

**Step 1**:

Create Build pipeline, and add `Powershell` task in it which names `BehindNoVerify`.

**Step 2**:

Add below script in that task after choose `inline` mode:

```
[String]$project = "$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECT"

[String]$OrgUri = "$env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI"

[String]$Repo = "$env:BUILD_REPOSITORY_NAME"

$headers = @{ Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN" }

$commiturl =$OrgUri + $project  + "/_apis/git/repositories/" + $Repo + "/commits?searchCriteria.itemVersion.version=master&api-version=5.1"

$comresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $commiturl -Headers $headers -Method Get

#Obtain the latest commit id value from master branch
$latestcommitid= $($comresponse.value.commitid[0])

$behindurl =$OrgUri + $project  + "/_apis/git/repositories/" + $Repo + "/stats/branches?baseVersionDescriptor.versionOptions=none&baseVersionDescriptor.version=" + $latestcommitid + "&baseVersionDescriptor.versionType=commit&api-version=5.1"

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $behindurl -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get

 #filter out the behind data of develop branch
$results = $response.value | Where {$_.name -eq "develop"} #|

Write-Host "results = $($results.behindCount | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"

 #Fail current task once behind value is non-zero
 if ($result -ne 0 ) {
    exit 128
  }
```

***Note:*** The work logic of above powershell script is **1).** [Obtain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20commits?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#on-a-branch) the latest `commit id` from `master` branch firstly. **2).** Use this `commit id` as the **target version** to compare to the commits of the `develop` branch, then calculate/obtain the `ahead` and `develop` number via this [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/stats/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1). **3)** Once the `behind` account is **non-zero**, modify the exit code to make the task fail manually.

*Above script can be applied to any org and project since I use environment variable to get the `Token`, `org name`, `project name` and `repos name`. Just enable [System.AccessToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#systemaccesstoken) is ok.*

[image]

**Step 3**

Go `branch policy` of corresponding branch => `Build validation` => `Add build policy` => Choose Build pipeline `BehindNoVerify` we defined previously.

Choose `Trigger` as **Automatic** and `Policy requirement` as **required**.

---

Now, the pull request allows be `completed` only when the pipeline(`BehindNoVerify`) runs successfully, that is, the value of `behind` is 0.

Comment: Hello,
I'm going through all my SO posts out of idle curiosity, and I noticed that I'd detected and fixed a probable typo in your answer, but never actually attempted to notify you of the typo (for shame!).
So just letting you know that the 
    `if ($result -ne 0 )`

part should probably actually be 
    `if ($results.behindCount -ne 0 )`

Answer (score 1):

I had to futz about a bit to get Mengdi Liang's snippet to work how I wanted it, so I figured I'd share my changes to save others a similar pain!
What I've done is genericised it to be triggered from a PR policy and compare master against the 'source' branch of the PR rather than "develop" specifically
I've also addressed what is probably a typo with `$result -ne 0` referencing $result rather than $results.behindcount, and so always failing.
Tested and works as of 2021-11-22

```
[String]$project = "$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECT"

[String]$OrgUri = "$env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI"

[String]$Repo = "$env:BUILD_REPOSITORY_NAME"

[String]$branch = "$env:SYSTEM_PULLREQUEST_SOURCEBRANCH"

$headers = @{ Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN" }

$commiturl =$OrgUri + $project  + "/_apis/git/repositories/" + $Repo + "/commits?searchCriteria.itemVersion.version=master&api-version=5.1"

$comresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $commiturl -Headers $headers -Method Get

#Obtain the latest commit id value from master branch
$latestcommitid= $($comresponse.value.commitid[0])

$behindurl =$OrgUri + $project  + "/_apis/git/repositories/" + $Repo + "/stats/branches?baseVersionDescriptor.versionOptions=none&baseVersionDescriptor.version=" + $latestcommitid + "&baseVersionDescriptor.versionType=commit&api-version=5.1"

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $behindurl -Headers $headers -Method Get

 #filter out the behind data of current PR branch
$results = $response.value | where-object { $_.name.indexof($branch.replace("refs/heads/","")) -ge 0 }

Write-Host "results = ${results.behindCount}"

 #Fail current task once behind value is non-zero
 if ($results.behindCount -ne 0 ) {
    exit 128
  }
```